# Rails ActiveRecord - retrieve data from association and relation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm learning the active model, and I'm trying to retrieve an association.

My models are:

```
class Composition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :materials
  belongs_to :product
end



class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :compositions
 has_many :products, through: :composition
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :compositions
  has_many :materials, through: :composition
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :materials
end
```

My schema is

```
  create_table "compositions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "material_id"
    t.integer  "material_quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  end


  create_table "materials", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "unit_cost"
    t.string   "unit_measure"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end


  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

On my CompositionsController index method, I would like to retrieve all raw materials for a product id.

Route is:

```
  resources :products do
    resources :compositions
  end
```

What i have  now is:

```
  def index
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @compositions = @product.compositions
  end
```

How do I retrieve materials attributes from @compositions?

When I try to use

```
@compositions = @product.compositions.includes(:materials)
```

It gives me the error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "compositions_materials" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"compositions_materials"'...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"compositions_materials"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

I think I'm missing something.
Any hints?

Thanks in advance,
Leandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, you should have `compositions_materials` table with `composition_id` and `material_id` columns (both integer).

More info about this kind of association here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: Wouldnt the ID on compositions table act as the ID? Should I explicit declare it? A select on compositions table no returns this:

id | product_id | material_id | material_quantity |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+------------+-------------+-------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  5 |          1 |           1 |                 3 | 2015-03-30 05:20:27.385293 | 2015-03-30 05:20:27.385293

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my models associations to only use **has_many through** and **belongs_to**:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :compositions
  has_many :materials, through: :composition
end

class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :compositions
 has_many :products, through: :composition
end

class Composition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :material, :class_name => "Material", :foreign_key => 'material_id'
  belongs_to :product
end
```

And I'm using this query to retrieve the attributes along the main result:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

@compositions = @product.compositions.includes(:material).references(:materials)
```

Comment: `belongs_to :material, :class_name => "Material", :foreign_key => 'material_id'` <=> `belongs_to :material`; use the shorter way if you're following the convention anyway.